# how to change this in a for loop?

Tags: python, computer-science

following is the code to be converted into for loop:

```
    num= int(input( 'enter a number' ))
    while num > 0 :
         print(num % 10)
         num/=10
```

look, the range in the for loop needs to keep on getting updated. But u cant do that using for loop. Ik it looks easy but idk how to do it. Now the below code needs to have a step value, otherwise it will return empty statement. But also I need the num value to change as the num variable keeps on getting assigned new values.

I tried doing like this but yeah not working.

```
num=int(input('enter a number'))
for num in range(num,0):
    print (num % 10)
    num/=10
```

the first six lines of output that the while loop gives is:

```
1
0.1
0.01
0.001
0.0001
1e-05
........
```

but how to display similar kinda output using for loop?

Comment: Why is there a hard requirement on it being a `for` loop? It does't look to be a good place to use a `for` loop. `for` loops are used to iterate on pre-defined container-like structures; this is perfect use for a `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

`for` loops in Python are different from `for` loops you might see of the form `for (;;)` in other languages such as C, C++, Java, Javascript, etc. Instead of iterating until a condition is false, Python `for` loops iterate until `StopIteration` is raised (this happens when you reach the "end" of iteration).

The only loop construct in Python that allows you to stop it conditionally after each iteration is the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop in this way `(num,0,-1)` to reverse the iteration

```
num= int(input( 'enter a number' ))
for i in range(num,0,-1):
    print(num % 10)
    num/=10
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter a number6
6
0.6
0.06
0.006
0.0006000000000000001
6.000000000000001e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a peculiar requirement, this can be achieved. So in Python, when you run  `for` loop with a `range` object as iterator, what you are essentially doing is you are iterating over the elements of the range object, which is basically a list of numbers. `for` loop runs until it has exhausted all the elements in the list. So a clever way to turn it into a while loop is to mutate the list in every line, that way, you never run out of elements. And you can pass the stopping condition of `while` loop through an `if` condition.

```
num= int(input( 'enter a number' ))
n = list(range(num+1))
for i in n :
    print(num % 10)
    num/=10
    n.append(1)
    if num<=0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this , or modify it further if it'll fit what you want.

`num=input()
z=int((0.9)*num)
for k in range(num,0,-z):
    z=int(math.round(0.9*k))
    print(z,k)
    print(k%10)`

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop your looking for should be based on a generator. Something like this will work :)

```py
def myrange(num):
    while num > 10**-15:
        num /= 10
        yield num

mynum = float(input(‘specify number:’))

for item in myrange(mynum):
    print(item % 10)
```